# What C++ operator is being overloaded here?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What operator is this code overloading? It doesn't look like the right syntax for the () operator.

```
class Example
{
public:
  operator bool() const;
...
};
```

It's used to simulate a boolean member variable, like this:

```
class Container
{
  public:
    Example ex;
}

void func()
{
  Container c;

  if (c.ex)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

Note that ex is used without the parentheses you'd expect from overloading the () operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `operator bool`, the [implicit conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) which allows your class to be used in a boolean context (like `if`).

Answer (score 2):

That is a [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).
It defines a user-defined conversion function that participates in all implicit and explicit conversions.